# news category filtering issue in exended class Contao

Tags: content-management-system, contao

I registered $GLOBALS['TL_HOOKS']['newsListFetchItems'][] hook in my news extended extension for sorting with my custom field (say 'rank'). But the pages which contain news filtering is not working .  I am using the contao Version 4.5.8 . How can I solve the issue.

```
    $t = \NewsModel::getTable();        
    $arrOptions = array();
    switch ($objModule->news_sorting)
    {
        case 'sort_rankid_asc':

            $arrOptions['order'] = "$t.rankid = 0, $t.rankid, $t.date DESC";              
            break;
        case 'sort_random':
            $arrOptions['order'] = "$t.date DESC";
            break;
        default:
            $arrOptions['order'] = "$t.date DESC";
    }

    return \NewsModel::findPublishedByPids($newsArchives, $blnFeatured, $limit, $offset, $arrOptions);
```

News filtering with category is not working after I added the above code.How Can I fix the issue

Comment: Your title mentions "news category filtering", but your description does not mention any of that. Did you enable any news category features in your news list module? If yes, then please provide a more detailed description.

Comment: I have news category filtering option in my news listing page. After adding the above hook the filtering is not working. I updated my question also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `codefog/contao-news_categories` extension in version `3.x` also uses the `newsListFetchItems` hook to filter the news list items (see [here](https://github.com/codefog/contao-news_categories/blob/3.0.13/src/Resources/contao/config/config.php#L45)). The hook will only work for one extension - which ever one returns something other than `false` first.

If you need both your custom sorting *and* filtering by a category, then you will need to implement the news category filtering yourself and you have to make sure that your hook is executed first.